# Can I use Selenium WebDriverWait to wait for xpath relative to a known web element?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Our application makes use of a generic drop down "Actions" button that looks like:

```
<div class="button dropdown petrocore-actions">
Actions
<ul class="no-hover" style="top: 30px;">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="OpenCreateGroupDialog('4')" data-selection="create">Create Group</a>
      </li>
  <li>
    <a id="lnkDelGroup_4" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ConfirmGroupDeletion('4')" data-selection="delete">Delete Group</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="OpenRenameGroupDialog('4')" data-selection="rename">Edit Group Name</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript: Navigate('link', '/groupadmin/4')" data-selection="view">View Group</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This button can be contained by any number of different types of objects within our application. The container object type will dictate the structure of the container div, where the actions button will sit relative to the container object and what the li contents of the drop down menu are.

I have created a page object class to represent this drop down button to encapsulate interactions like expanding/collapsing the menu, returning its contents, clicking on one of its selections ...etc. The actions button class constructor takes a Selenium WebElement for the container of the button. When the button is clicked to be expanded I would like to use `WebDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Xpath(<xpath relative to container WebElement>)))` but I can only figure out how to use an xpath for the entire DOM which may contain any number of these action buttons which are only identifiable by there container type and ID.

I have run into other situations where I want to set up a WebDriverWait for xpath relative to a known webelement as well. I am quite new to working with Selenium and C# programming for that matter. Thanks for your time and consideration on this question.

Comment: Are you saying there could a good number of **Actions** button and want to wait for all of them?

Comment: No, I don't want to wait for the existence of all action buttons. I want to wait for the class attribute of the UL for a specific action button on the page to contain 'show-dropdown' when it is finished expanding after a click. Problem is that there is nothing in the action buttons XML that conveniently contains an ID indicator for it's parent. Which is why I want to WebDriverWait for xpath ".//ul[contains(@class,'show-dropdown']" relative to the parent WebElement I used to create the Actions button instance. Thank you for the clarification question.

Comment: .. and yes, there could be a good number of Actions buttons on the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
WebElement container = webDriver.findElement(By.id('your-container-id'));
WebDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(container.findElement(By.Xpath(<xpath relative to container WebElement>))));
```

Answer (score 1):

The element object has the same findElement mechanism as the driver itself. The gotcha is though that if you use a standard path expression it will search from the top of the DOM despite being called from within an element.

You need to modify your xpath so that it begins

```
self::*/
```

Or

```
./
```

Rather than;

```
//
```

This will now restrict the xpath to the context of the parent element.

The web driver wait mechanism will also except any code that returns a Boolean, as well as the built in helper methods you are already using.

So to recap, call findElement on the element, change your xpath as described above, and create a custom wait mechanism within WebdriverWait

Comment: Thanks Robbie. I understand the necessity to include the 'self' reference for a context starting point for the xpath passed to the element objects findElement. It is the second piece of your response about creating a custom wait method to test the element relative findElement response that I wasn't making the leap to. I will look into how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do text based search and see if the same `div` contains the text called **Actions**

```
By xpath = By.XPaht("//div[contains(@class,'button dropdown')][contains(text(),'Actions')]");

WebDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(xpath));
```

Comment: This xpath wouldn't uniquely identify a specific **Actions** button on the page as it would still match all of the actions buttons. This is why I want to search for an xpath relative to the WebElement parent my Selenium Actions button page object was instantiated from.

Comment: Then provide the entire html. Writing xpath should not be a big issue

Comment: I appreciate your time and help and I apologize if the example I was trying to describe created the perception that I need help defining an xpath string but this is not really what I'm trying to determine. My question was if/how can I use Selenium's WebDriverWait class to wait for an xpath that is relative to a specific Selenium WebElement object rather than relative to the entire DOM.

Comment: Much like the difference between finding a webelement via the WebDriver rather than from another WebElement.

i.e.
Driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='button dropdown'"))
vs.
WebElement.FindElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='button dropdown'"))

Comment: The element look up with XPATH does not make Selenium wait for Entire DOM to load. Why are you making that assumption or is that proven? That could have solved a lot of Ajax related issue if Selenium could do that btw.