# How to use selenium explicit driver wait using xpath relative to anothe webelement in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am looping through a list of web elements like below:

```
all_articles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[@class='jobs posts-loop ']/div[2]/div/article")

for index , eachArticle in enumerate(all_articles):
    try:
        # WebDriverWait(driver , 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(eachArticle.find_element(By.XPATH,".//h2/a")))
        WebDriverWait(eachArticle , 3).until(lambda x : x.find_element_by_xpath("/h2/a"))
    except Exception as ttt:
        exception_log.exception(ttt)
```

I want to wait until the presence of an element whose XPath is relative to the item of the loop. The above code doesn't work and gives me an exception whereas If I don't use waitDriverWait it works fine. The below code looks fine

```
op_link = eachArticle.find_element_by_xpath(".//h2/a").get_attribute("href")
```

My intention is to wait for it before getting direct access to the element because sometimes the driver breaks and can't find the element it might be due to the internet connection speed. Anyway, how to achieve that. These links gave me some idea but as I tried I could not get the desired output.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46963104/selenium-explicit-wait-with-relative-xpath-locator)

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346386/can-i-use-selenium-webdriverwait-to-wait-for-xpath-relative-to-a-known-web-eleme)

Comment: Please post the full exception message, properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Three things jump out at me in your initial code.

1. `WebDriverWait` expects a driver instance and you've passed it a WebElement. It should be

   ```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
   ```

   as in your commented out code.
2. Presence is that the element exists in the DOM, not that it's visible or interactable. You should wait for clickable if you want to click it, visible otherwise.
3. If you are locating an element FROM an element with XPath, your XPath needs to start with a `.`. Your `/h2/a` should be `./h2/a` if the element you are searching for is a child of `eachArticle` or `.//h2/a` if it is a descendant.

Your commented out line looks pretty close... just change `presence_of_element_located` to `element_to_be_clickable` and you should be good.

Comment: thank you for the answer, following your answer 1-I tried both ways as someone suggested that we can put web element instead of the driver as well hence I tried it didn't work. 2-I am trying to use presence since as I see in the dom it is always present there but It sometimes still gives me an error that's why I am trying to explicitly wait for its presence. 3-it is a descendant element that's why I use two dots. to sum up, my commented line code should work fine.